# Referrer disappearing after redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, referrer

I have a redirect script which does some tracking and then redirects the user to a destination. It looks something like this

```
class Redirect() {
  private function init() {
    // analyze parameters
    (...)

    $this->referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

    $this->trackVisit($this->referer, $someMoreData);

    $destination = $this->getUrlByParameters(...);

    $this->redirectUrl = $destination;
  }

  private function run() {
    (...)
    header('Location: ' . $this->redirectUrl);
    (...)
  }
}

$r = new Redirect();
if($r->init()) {
  $r->run();
}
```

What gives me headache is that i can see a referrer on my server and i am saving that in to my db but after redirecting the user it disappears. The destination and all possible subsequent redirects don't have the referrer anymore.

Referrer-Policy is set to 'no-referrer-when-downgrade' but i am always redirect to https so that should not be the issue.

I hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the request from a script using `header("Location:...")` The ŕeferrer will not be preserved. You could possibly pass the referer as a variable in query string:

```
header('Location: ' . $this->redirectUrl."?ref=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

or with &, if the URL already contains some parameters. 
Then you could get the original referer on the other script using `$_GET["ref"]`

Or you could write headers yourself and append it before the `Location` header, and then send full headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as i know, adding the referer to the header myself will do nothing because most browsers will ignore it anyway. What would be a solid solution if i don't own the destination because telling all the sites that there is a parameter to look for is not an option? Will meta-refresh 0 work?

Comment: Yes, meta-refresh will preserve original headers, so I think it's a good option for your case. Sorry for a late response, but I was gone for a weekend and couldn't get here any sooner.